# flutter dart Try/Catch not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, exception, try-catch

While learning flutter/dart, I came across this issue:

I'm calling this method in a FutureBuilder somewhere in my app:

```
  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      return user;
    } on UserDoesNotExistsException {
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Once called for the first time, the "getUser" throws a UserDoesNotExistsException, which is correct, so it should go to the line:

```
} on UserDoesNotExistsException {
```

This is the issue, it always goes straight to the line:

```
} catch (e) {
```

If I print (e), I have UserDoesNotExistsException (see screenshot)

Let me know if you need more context here, what could make sense in that situation? Why is the Exception not caught by the right bloc?

Any help would be really appreciated

PS: I'm following this 37h+ video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPvVD8t02U8&t=28781s I'm at 21:36:00

Thanks

[Screenshot Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36uxx.png)

Comment: Could you print the result of `print(e.runtimeType);` and `print(e is UserDoesNotExistsException);`?

Comment: If you have enabled the following lint in your analyzer, it should at least have given you a warning about trying to throw an object that does not implement `Exception` or `Error`: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/only_throw_errors.html . But good to hear your problem have been solved. :)

Comment: @vgross, you can answer your own question with the solution. It's going to be more visible to others to check the given solution as an answer than trying to read the comments here.

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved.

As julemand101 suggested, a ***print(e.runtimeType)*** exposed the type of ***e*** as ***Type*** and not ***Exception***.

The reason was a missing ***()*** when the Exception is thrown:

```
if (result.isEmpty) {
  throw UserDoesNotExistsException;
} else {
  return DatabaseUser.fromRow(result.first);
}
```

instead of

```
if (result.isEmpty) {
  throw UserDoesNotExistsException();
} else {
  return DatabaseUser.fromRow(result.first);
}
```

Visual Studio Code doesn't give any warning about this by default, but as julemand101 suggested in the comments, the analyzer can be configured to give a warning when you don't throw an Error or Exception:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/only_throw_errors.html